# Deleting an entry in database and verify that it has been deleted - still finding the entry after deleting it

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, junit

I have a JDCB program that connects to a MySQL database, and doing things like adding tables, adding entries, removing entries etc.

I have a problem in a test where i wanna do these steps:

1. Add a entry to my database table.
2. Check that the entry exists.
3. Remove the entry.
4. Verify that the entry no longer exists.

Here is my code:

```java
testConn = database.getConn();

try {
    String addEntry = "INSERT INTO HighScore(ID, username, " +
        "Score) VALUES" +
        "(ID, 'testAddEntry',333)";

    st = testConn.createStatement();
    st.execute(addEntry);


    String findEntry = "SELECT * FROM HighScore WHERE " +
        "username='testAddEntry'";

    st.execute(findEntry);

    assertTrue(st.execute(findEntry));

    String deleteEntry = "DELETE FROM HighScore WHERE " +
        "username='testAddEntry'";

    st.execute(deleteEntry);

    String findEntryNow = "SELECT * FROM HighScore WHERE " +
        "username='testAddEntry'";

    System.out.println(st.execute(findEntryNow));
    assertFalse(st.execute(findEntryNow));

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the problem is that `assertFalse(st.execute(findEntryNow));` should return false, but it returns true. And when I check the database the entry is not there. ( i have tried to only add and remove it, so that 100% works).

The problem is i want to run a execute that looks for it but verifies that the entry is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of the return value of [`Statement.execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-):

> **Returns**:
>   `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if it is an update count or there are no results

A select query always has a result, and that result is a `ResultSet`, even if it is empty. The *"there are no results"* in this documentation refers to statements that produce no results at all (no update counts nor result sets).

So the return value of `execute(String)` does not indicate the presence or absence of rows. If you want to check that, you need to check `ResultSet.next()`, or - alternatively - query the count and check that that count is 0.

Option 1:

```
String findEntryNow = "SELECT * FROM HighScore WHERE " +
        "username='testAddEntry'";
try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(findEntryNow)) {
    assertFalse(rs.next());
}
```

Option 2

```
String findEntryCount = "SELECT count(*) FROM HighScore WHERE " +
        "username='testAddEntry'";
try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(findEntryNow)) {
    assertTrue(rs.next()); // even absence of entries will produce a row
    assertEquals(0, rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which version of MySQL you are using, but from the docs MySQL Connector/J 5.1

> If you do not know ahead of time whether the SQL statement will be a
>   SELECT or an UPDATE/INSERT, then you can use the execute(String SQL)
>   method. This method will return true if the SQL query was a SELECT, or
>   false if it was an UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement. If the
>   statement was a SELECT query, you can retrieve the results by calling
>   the getResultSet() method. If the statement was an UPDATE, INSERT, or
>   DELETE statement, you can retrieve the affected rows count by calling
>   getUpdateCount() on the Statement instance.

This states that if you use execute to run a SELECT you will always get true.

From this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements.html

You will actually need to get the result set and confirm it is empty.